# Afterthought expressions other than "d'ailleurs" to mean "I might add"?

Tags: traduction, expressions

> Il n'est malheureusement pas toujours sobre. Quand il ne fait pas faux bond, **d'ailleurs**.

---

The second sentence is said jocularly and as somewhat of an afterthought to express that:

"Most of the time he’s a no-show. And even when he does show up, he’s rarely sober on stage."

---

In order to express the following ideas in brackets, what phrase apart from "d'ailleurs" can you use?

> Unfortunately, he’s not always sober on stage. When he does show up, {**I might add** / **that is** / **mind you**}.
>
> Unfortunately, he’s not always sober on stage. {**I’m talking about**} when he does show up.
>
> Unfortunately, he’s not always sober on stage. If he does show up {**in the first place**}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few possibilities:

> Il n'est malheureusement pas toujours sobre. Quand il ne fait pas carrément faux bond.
>
> Il n'est malheureusement pas toujours sobre. Quand toutefois il ne fait pas faux bond.
>
> Il n'est malheureusement pas toujours sobre. Enfin, quand il ne fait pas faux bond...

**EDIT** about *carrément*:

In this context, it's to show the second case is 'more *something*' than the first one:

> Il n'est pas seulement grand, il est carrément gigantesque ! = He's not just tall, he is a giant!

Note that it doesn't mean 'he is *something* + *something else*', but 'he is not *that*, he is even more than *that*'.

If I'm right, '***Not only** is he kind, but he also is beautiful*' means '*He is kind AND beautiful*', but '*He's **not just** kind, he's adorable*' means '*He is **more than** kind, he is [carrément] adorable*'. So I suppose '*He is **even more than** kind [...]*' could be a good translation for *carrément*.

When I say *more* it can be *more* in different meanings: *more... little*, *more... bad*, *more whatever*. So you have to understand, for this case, that *not coming* is worse than *coming drunk* (of course it may not really be worse, but it means that sometimes he doesn't *even* deign to come, compared to when he comes drunk).

Another usage would be an informal synonym of *très* : '*Il fait carrément froid aujourd'hui !*', same language than '*You're dead right!*' ('*T'as carrément raison !*'). The first comparative meaning is probably implied in this second meaning. So you could say '*Il est carrément adorable !*' without any comparison with something less than adorable, and it becomes an informal way of saying *really adorable*.

I hope I made myself understandable.

Comment: Merci. I'm not sure what "carrément" means in this context.

Comment: @LUNA I edited my reply

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially use

> Soit dit en passant

which is an idiomatic expression roughly equivalent to 'I might add'.

The literal translation is:

> Be said in passing

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

To translate *in the first place*:

> Quand **dans un premier temps** il ne fait pas faux bond.
>
> Quand il ne fait pas faux bond **dans un premier temps**.
>
> Quand, **pour commencer** il ne fait pas faux bond.

To translate *we might add/I might add*:

> Quand il ne fait pas faux bond, **pourrait-on ajouter**.
>
> Quand il ne fait pas faux bond, **ajouterais-je**.

Another suggestion:

> **Encore faut-il** qu'il ne **fasse** pas faux bond.

Note that you also can replace *quand* by *si* in each suggestion.